# Need advice for CSS for the button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I have an asp.net page. There is sidebar in which there are several buttons. There is another button "Edit". 
Please look at my image:
[image]

My question: I don't want the button "Edit" displayed unless a button in the sidebar is clicked.
Rightnow it is defaulted show up. My goal is "Edit" doesn't show uncless say click "Problems1" then "Edit" will show up underneath the gridview.
My code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebTest._Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<div id="wrap">
 <div id="sidebar">
        <asp:Button ID="p1" runat="server" Text="Problems1" CssClass="sidebar_buttons"
         OnClientClick="Edit_Click()" />
        <asp:Button ID="p2" runat="server" Text="Problems2" CssClass="sidebar_buttons"
             />
        <asp:Button ID="p3" runat="server" Text="Problem3" CssClass="sidebar_buttons" />
        <asp:Button ID="p4" runat="server" Text="Problem4" CssClass="sidebar_buttons" />
        <asp:Button ID="p5" runat="server" Text="Problem5" CssClass="sidebar_buttons" />
        <asp:Button ID="p6" runat="server" Text="Problem6" CssClass="sidebar_buttons" />
        <asp:Button ID="p7" runat="server" Text="Problem7" CssClass="sidebar_buttons" />
    </div>
    <div id="gridview">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
      <div id="btnEdit" >
        <asp:Button ID="Edit" runat="server"  Text="Edit" /></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#wrap
{
     width: 800px;
     background-color: #99c;
}
#sidebar
{
    float: left;
    width: 125px;
    padding-top:10px;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
#gridview
{
    float: right;
    width: 675px;
}

.sidebar_buttons
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 120px;
 }

#btnEdit
{
   float: inherit;
}
```

Comment: I still don't see a question.  And what have you tried?

Comment: My question: I don't want the button "Edit" displayed unless clicking a button on sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all hide your edit button by inserting this property in your

```
#btnEdit
{
   float: inherit;
   display:none; //hide your edit button
}
```

then call jQuery function on click and show the edit button like

```
$("#button").click(function(){
     $("#btnEdit").show();
});
```

Comment: There is a chance that code will not work since at the run time asp.net will probably change the name of the button to something else. Either use **CssClass** property or **<%= button.ClientID %>**

Comment: You should be able to resolve this by setting `ClientIDMode` to `Static` on the button.

Answer (score 2):

In the aspx code, set the edit button to visible=false. Go into the properties of the other buttons, go into the events and double click the 'Click' event and place code to make the button visible :)

Hope this helps

Comment: This will work, but it will require a postback. I like jassi9911's solution better.

Answer (score 1):

first you add display:none; to the css of btnEdit

```
#btnEdit
{
    display:none;
}
```

Then you use Jquery to show the btnEdit when the "Problem1Button" is clicked (replace it by the ID of your button)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Problem1Button").click(function (event) {
    $("#btnEdit").show();            

    });
}
</script>
```